# Vim plugin to open a shell in a split window

Tags: vim, vim-plugins

Are there any vim plugins for creating a split window with a shell inside? Almost like a split window with the `:sh` command contained inside. I also can't use something like `screen` becuase this is in MacVim (`gvim` for Mac OS X).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have not used it (I found it in [an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236563/how-to-run-a-terminal-inside-of-vim/2913996#2913996)), but [Conque](http://code.google.com/p/conque/) is a Vim plugin that seems like it might do what you want: in a (possibly split) Vim window, interact with a spawned program over a pty with a decent amount of terminal emulation<sup>*</sup>. It requires Vim 7 with Python support and it indicates that MacVim automatically comes with it.

<sup>* Vim does not do any terminal emulation itself, which is a problem when trying to use termcap- or terminfo-based software in a `:shell` under GUI-based instances of Vim (see [`:help gui-pty`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_x11.html#gui-pty)).</sup>

Comment: I agree with Chris Johnsen. For simple tasks, Conque plugin (https://github.com/vim-scripts/Conque-Shell) is very nice. I use also Conque-GDB plugin (https://github.com/vim-scripts/Conque-GDB) to use gdb debugger (for C/C++) as simple IDE INSIDE Vim. Fantastic. With Conque you can open many shell / script inside every vim Window/Tab. Nevertheless if you need SPEED, let consider reverse the point of view: let use tmux (https://tmux.github.io/)...

Comment: apart slowness Conque terminal emulator seem to not work very weel with dynamic stdout printout, by example you can't do a really working "watch -n2 "ls -l" inside a Conque termnal inside a vim window... That's why the definitive solution could be using tmux... even if I repeat I love Conque plugins!

Answer (score 1):

The answers given to this question may be of use to you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671583/how-does-one-make-a-vim-window-a-full-on-terminal

Answer (score 0):

[VimShell](https://github.com/Shougo/vimshell.vim) is a shell-teminal implementation for vim. It is one of the kind with its own flavour, but definitely fits for simple tasks, and may be you will like it to use it on a regular basis.